# "contentId is required!" with ZK framework

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, zk

I am using ZK Framework (v6.0.1) to development a web application with file upload feature. 
After I deployed the war file to Tomcat, hit the button and uploaded a file to web server, it shows "**contentId is required!**" error message, but **nothing wrong showed on Tomcat's catalina.out**, I was expecting to see a stack trace, I could not get any clue from Tomcat's log. 
The deployment environment I used:

- Sun JDK 6u29
- Tomcat 7.0.28
- ZK EE 6.0.1

Note: Strange enough. I cannot get the "contentId is required!" error while using **run-jetty-run** Eclipse plugin, **is this means this problem only occurred when I use Tomcat as the web container**?

Comment: I've resolve this problem, it was due to database configuration mistake. It tried to insert a record into the database but failed to do it.